# A child widget is transparent to events when parent is set after child creation

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I have a qt application that is comprised of a main window and a settings window that I am trying to port to Qt5.

I use `QWidget::setParent()` to set my settings window exactly on top of(and cover) my main window, and prior to using qt5.1.1 (the previous version I used was qt 4.8.5) this method worked fine.

The problem I have right now is that the settings window is being displayed correctly but almost all mouse events(minus the mouse over on some of the buttons) are being passed directly to the main window which is underneath.

I have tried setting different flags for the settings window to no effect.

This issue does not reproduce on windows.

I've being searching for a solution to this problem for some time now.

I am using qt 5.1.1 on MacOSX 10.7.5

Comment: I believe when you set a widget to be a child of a window, you add it to the window's layout. So the events go to the parent window and then to the widget.

Comment: @headsvk it's weird that it works ok on windows or previous versions of Qt4. I realize that my settings window is being added to the layout but I still think it should get the events first, since it is over the main window. I'm thinking that this might be a bug in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with overlapping siblings. When you reparent the settings window, it has various siblings inside of the main window that overlap it. This seems to have undefined behavior, as you've just learned. Your window is *not* added to any layout merely by being reparented. If it was added to the layout (except for stacked layouts), you wouldn't have this problem, and of course it wouldn't look right either.

A portable solution would involve using either:

1. A `QStackedLayout` as the base layout within the main window. Note that this won't work for `QMainWindow`, `QScrollArea` and similar windows that don't have container layouts applied directly.
2. A `QStackedWidget` as the base widget class, with your `QMainWindow` or similar class inserted into it.

In both cases, you temporarily insert your settings window into the stack, and flip the pages.

Note that this behavior is questionable from user experience perspective.

Comment: I tried using a QStackedLayout and it works ok, since my settings window is transparent I used setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll) and it looks the same like it used to. Thanks for the help.